# Loop module not present on Ubuntu installation

Tags: kernel, loop-device

`sudo modprobe loop max_loop=255` does not return an error, but `lsmod | grep "loop"` returns nothing. Likewise `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name "loop.ko"` doesn't print any paths to the screen.

I'd think that this was because it was missing, but if I use `modprobe` to load a nonsense name, then I get an error that it doesn't exist.

So, where is the kernel module `loop`? Does it exist at all?

Comment: What is loop module and why do you want it?

Comment: @Pilot6 It's for Xen. Apparently it's built-in to Linux on this distro. But I need to change `max_loop` to 255.

Comment: I updated the answer. You can use a boot parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely compiled into the kernel, rather than being available as a separate loadable module: for example, on my 14.04 system

```
~$ grep 'loop' /lib/modules/`uname -r`/modules.builtin
kernel/drivers/block/loop.ko
```

See this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) discussion: [Linux Loadable modules and built-in modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929065/linux-loadable-modules-and-built-in-modules).

Answer (score 1):

`loop` must be compiled into the kernel and not built as a `ko` module.

That is why it does not appear in `lsmod`.

You can change `max_loop` as a boot parameter.

The parameter is called `max_loop=255`. You can set it in `/etc/default/grub` in line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

Then run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I rebooted and added `loop.max_loop=255` to the kernel command line. `cat /sys/module/loop/parameters/max_loop` currently returns `255`, but `xen-create-image` is still telling me to execute `modprobe loop max_loop=255`.

Comment: This is another question.